How can I check if a transfer initiated with `aws s3 cp` was 100% successful?
I've uploaded a large number of files and folders to an AWS S3 bucket via:
aws s3 cp . s3://mybucket --recursive

How can I check if the transfer was 100% successful?

Possible Duplicate ? How can one copy an S3 bucket as faithfully as possible (e.g., copying all permission settings)?

@djdomi thanks, no, I'm not copying a bucket here, just uploading a few files. I used cp and now I wonder how to check.

In addition s3 Browser (product suggestions are offtopic) has the ability to compare

@djdomi thanks, I'll write an answer just using cp. Hopefully it'll illustrate why the questions are different.

One can use sync:
aws s3 sync . s3://mybucket 

It only uploads the files that are missing in the S3 bucket. No need to add --recursive since sync is always recursive.
(Thanks Reddit user p0093 for mentioning the command.)

One can use --only-show-errors: if the transfer is 100% successful, then nothing will be output.
Documentation:

--only-show-errors (boolean) Only errors and warnings are displayed. All other output is suppressed.

Example:
aws s3 cp . s3://mybucket --recursive --only-show-errors


remember that you need to accept your answer in 24 hours please. Else we will be reminded until the end of the universe to solve this problem ;)
